# Model a class from a string of Html, instantiate the class and populate variables from the string, and return the html string from the class

Tags: java, html, xml, jaxb, xsd

This may be kind of difficult to explain, but I'm trying to create a Java class from a string of html markup.  I'd like to be able to take the string and create an object and populate all the member variables with the values.  From there I'd also like to be able to take that object and have it spit back the html markup.  The html markup is technically XML so I have to think this is possible.  Here's a quick snippet of the html string -- it's fairly straight forward.  There's a map tag with 0 to many area tags as children.

```
<map id="..." name="...">
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="68,67,159,159" href="/" target="_self" />
<area shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="217,43,344,148" href="google.com" target="" />
....
</map>
```

Anyone know of any java libraries to ease this process?  I'm struggling.

Comment: Are you asking for libraries that parse XML in Java? If so a quick google search will show you tons of options.

Comment: Yes, I know, I've used these libraries before. I guess I'm just looking for a lib that's geared more towards XML that's actually Html. I don't know just feels a little different for me.

Comment: "XML that's actually HTML". Is it valid XML or not? If so, use an XML library.

Comment: It is valid XML. Sorry, I didn't mean to pose a dumb question, and honestly feel that the down vote is unnecessary. I don't have much experience working with XML in Java so was looking for some pointers.

Comment: I did not downvote you, but whoever did probably did so because your question is overly broad.

Comment: Yes, that's why I started the question with - "This may be kind of difficult to explain."  Ehh, whatever, it's the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach this with a combination of [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) and either [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/) or [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

JTidy will help you to clean the HTML mark-up which is not necessary valid XHTML.

JAXB or XStream could then be used to unmarshal XHTML into Java objects and marshal them back in XML Form.

I am, so to speak, *more familiar* with JAXB so I'll sketch the JAXB way.

With JAXB, you'd take the some XML Schema of XHTML, for instance [XHTML 1.0 Strict Schema](http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd) and compile it using JAXB's schema compiler, the [XJC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html).

Compilation most probably won't succed from the very start because of the some naming collision. For instance, `xml:lang` and `lang` attributes will map to the same `lang` property in the Java class. At this point you'll need to use a [binding file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) to customize the XML Schema -> Java derivation.

Here's how it could look like for the schema mentined above:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="org.hisrc.w3c.xhtml.v_1_0_strict"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>

        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:attributeGroup[@name='i18n']/xs:attribute[@ref='xml:lang']">
            <jaxb:property name="xmlLang"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='bdo']/xs:complexType/xs:complexContent/xs:extension/xs:attribute[@ref='xml:lang']">
            <jaxb:property name="xmlLang"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

When you (hopefully) finally succeed, you'll get a package of some 90+ Java classes which are derived from the XHTML 1.0 Strict XML Schema. You'll get classes like `Map` and `Area` with properties for all the elements and attributes you have in your schema.

Having these classes you could now unmarshal your XML (ideally pre-processed with JTidy). This would look like:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.hisrc.w3c.xhtml.v_1_0_strict");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<Map> mapElement = (JAXBElement<Map>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);
Map map = mapElement.getValue();
List<Area> areas = map.getArea();
```

Now you have your `map` and `area`s and do whatever you want with them on Java level.

Finally, you could marhsal your `map` back to some result:

```
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
JAXBElement<Map> mapElement = new JAXBElement<Map>(
    new QName("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "map"),
    Map.class, map);
marshaller.marshal(mapElement, result);
```

So this is it more or less.

(Both code snippets above are just sketches and were not tested.)

---

Now a small warning. JAXB is a very good tool for strongly-structured schemas. XHTML falls in the category of "semi-structured" since it allows a lot of mixed content, elements in arbitrary order and so on. These asre things which sometimes look ugly in JAXB schema-derived classes. For instance, you'll get a property like:

```
@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name = "object", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", type = org.hisrc.w3c.xhtml.v_1_0_strict.Object.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "label", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", type = Label.class, required = false),
    // 28 lines skipped
    @XmlElementRef(name = "strong", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", type = Strong.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "abbr", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", type = Abbr.class, required = false)
})
@XmlMixed
protected List<java.lang.Object> content;
```

Which is not really nice. So JAXB may be somewhat suboptimal for the task

---

Finally, *a small advertisement block*.

**Disclaimer:** I lead a small open-source project which is called [w3c-schemas](https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas). This project compiles some of the W3C Schemas with JAXB (for instance, [XLink](https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas/tree/master/xlink/1999) or [XML Schema](https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas/tree/master/XMLSchema/2001) itself). The goal of the project is to provide ready-to-use schema-derived classes compiled from these schemas - or binding files which could be used for compilation.

So when answering your question I have just added XHTML 1.0 Strict to my project. You can access the relevant module here:

- https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas/tree/master/xhtml/1.0-Strict

Below is the bindings file you could use when compiling the XHTML 1.0 Strict schema on your own:

- https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas/blob/master/xhtml/1.0-Strict/src/main/resources/xhtml-v_1.0-strict.xjb

This is basically the same bindings file I posted as a code snippet above.

**Note to the reviewers:** In this answer I do refer to my own project. However, if the OP opts to use JAXB, the module and code I refer to match the question very well.